# How to read targz folder in memory using nodejs

Tags: node.js, tar, unzip

I have tar.gz folder like

- config

  - f1
  - f2
  - myfile.json
  - myfile2.json
    .
    .
    .
    .

I want to get the content for myfile.json , myfile2.json in memory without storing on disk using  nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `tar-stream` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar-stream) and `gunzip-maybe` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gunzip-maybe).

The former allows you to read the contents of a file inside a tar archive into memory, while the latter can transform a gzipped tar file into a normal tar file on the fly.

The package documentations contain examples of how to use them.